# Showing Specific image from Dir.glob index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dir

I have a products controller where i show all my images available in a certain folder:

```
def index
  @images = Dir.glob("app/assets/images/database/*.jpg")
end
```

Now i'm trying to link each image to an individual dynamic show page:

```
def show
  @images = Dir.glob("app/assets/images/database/" + params[:id] + ".jpg")
end
```

Sadly i get an error `"no implicit conversion of nil into String"` for quite a while now.

Ideally i want to automatic render all the images from the database folder on the index page and link them individually to the show action where i use exifr to get specific information about each image.

Comment: `params[:id]` is nil. Hence the error. Also, why use `Dir.glob` when you want a single image?

Comment: I'm not sure of an alternative method :/

Answer (score 0):

```
def show
  @images = Dir.glob("app/assets/images/database/" + params[:id] ||
                     "no-image" + ".jpg")
end
```

It's not a good practice. You should use any image uploader and set teh default image. E.g. for CarrierWave:

```
class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def default_url(*args)
    "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  end
end
```

Comment: because you don't have an image file there. You should create it explicitly.